# Django authorization when calling other view

Tags: python, django, session, url, request

I have a django system for building formsheets on refrigeration systems.

I have a model called System.

I have plenty of models which represent a form paper and many have :

1. a Foreign key to System called anlage
2. a Method called get_pdf_url which returns an url to the pdf generator for the instance
3. an Attribute CLASSNAME

This is the get method from the zip view :

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    print('# AnlageZip GET NEU ###################################################################################################')
    self.pk=self.kwargs.get('pk')
    self.template_name = "stammdat/Anlage/info.html"
    self.user=self.request.user
    #
    host=self.request.get_host()
    try :
        an=Anlage.objects.filter(user=self.request.user).get(pk=self.pk)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist :
        an=None
    #
    tfile=BytesIO()
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile( tfile, "w" )
    # Leere Liste erzeugen
    AnlageFiles=[]
    #
    seq=1
    x={}
    x['Filename'] = '{:02d}_{}.pdf'.format(seq,an.CLASSNAME)
    x['pdf_url']   = 'http://'+host+an.get_pdf_url()
    x['data']       = urllib.request.urlopen( x['pdf_url'] )
    #x['data1']      = 
    AnlageFiles.append(x)
    print(x['Filename'],x['pdf_url'])
    zf.writestr( x['Filename'],x['data'].read())
    seq+=1
    # Jetzt Dokumentation suchen 
    # Alle diese modelle benötigen einen foreign Key zu Anlage namens anlage
    #
    DokuModels = [KurzBetrAnleitA1, KurzBetrAnleitA3, KurzBetrAnleitNH3, UebernahmeUebergabeKurz,UebernahmeUebergabe, 
                  SichDruckBegrenz,DruckFestPruef,AbnahmPruefDruckbeh,WiederPruefDruckbeh,AbnahmPruefRohr,WiederPruefRohr,
                  PruefListSicht,PruefBeschWK8901,Wartungsvertrag,Einbauerklaerung,
                  EGKonformErkl,Instandhaltungsvertrag,RisikoBeurteilung]
    #
    for doku in DokuModels :
        docs=doku.objects.filter(anlage=an)
        if len(docs) > 0 :
            for item in docs :
                x={}
                x['Filename']      = '{:02d}_{}.pdf'.format(seq,item.CLASSNAME)
                x['pdf_url']    = 'http://'+host+item.get_pdf_url()
                x['data']       = urllib.request.urlopen( x['pdf_url'] )
                AnlageFiles.append(x)
                zf.writestr( x['Filename'],x['data'].read())
                seq+=1
    zf.close()
    #
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/x-zip-compressed')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="Anlage_{}.zip'.format(self.pk)
    response.write(tfile.getvalue())
    tfile.close()
    return response
```

There is a View called SytemOverView
it checks all models for a foreign key to System
if they have one,
it calls the get_pdf_url Method
and creates a context for a list
You can click the urls and get the pdf (up to 54) in the View, works fine

Now I created a ZIP view to download all pdf's in one go
but my pdf files in the zip only contain the login page html code
as the requests query is not authorized.

How can I reuse the django session for the system zip view to launch
the requests for all pdf's?

Comment: I suspect your ZIP view calls PDF views via server calls?

Comment: Yes, it does. Currenty I try to amend the request/session from the ZipView and use it to authorize the server calls to the pdf view. Some example or tipps would be great. 
Currently I study the software django-batch-requests to find hints on how to solve this. I use Django 1.9.5/1.9.7 and Python 3.4

Comment: your ZipView can call the view functions by forwarding the request object, and use the same session.

Comment: Do you have some example James?

Comment: I think you should show me some of your code first

Comment: I have added the get method from the zip view, it is mainly a copy from the view for the html page. There I need the List/Dict for context.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in the comments, you are making an external call to your own website, you should call the pdf view directly pass along the request object to retain the session as below, but it seems it bit difficult to modify the request object to construct your different PDFs

```
def pdf_view(request):
   ...
   # construct pdf
   ...
   return pdf_response

def zipview(request):

   pdf1 = pdf_view(request)
   pdf2 = pdf_view(request)
   # do the zip
```

I recommend refactor out the pdf function as below:

```
def generate_pdf(...):
   ...
   return pdf

def pdf_view(request):
   ...
   return generate_pdf(..)

def zip_view(request):

   pdf1 = generate_pdf(params)
   pdf2 = generate_pdf(params)
   # do the zip
```

Comment: the pdf generation gets a dictionary from the pdf_view and runs as separate process already using fproc.communicate() ...

Comment: the pdf generation gets a dictionary from the pdf_view and runs as separate process already using fproc.communicate() ...

What I really want to do is use the url. 

Maybe I can create a javascript function in the view with the url list inside and then run the zip generator in the browser on click of a zip button. That would use the existing session. I will try that the next days.

Answer (score 0):

Use the session from the connected client and a simple javascript function to collect the files.

In the template of the django view I create a script that collects all pdf files from the page and builds a zip file from it.

```
<input id="zipme" type="button" value="Create Zip File (takes some time ...)" onclick="CreateZip();" class="btn btn-primary hidden-print btn-block" />

<script src="/static/js/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="/static/js/FileSaver.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

function CreateZip(){
    var zip = new JSZip();
    var zaehler=0
    {% for formdata in Doku %}
        var {{formdata.blob}} = null;
        var {{formdata.request}} = new XMLHttpRequest();
        {{formdata.request}}.open("GET", "{{ formdata.pdf_url }}" );
        //{{formdata.request}}.onload = function(){
        //  {{formdata.blob}} = {{formdata.request}}.responseText;
        //}
        {{formdata.request}}.send();
        zaehler=zaehler+1;
        //
        {{formdata.request}}.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if ({{formdata.request}}.readyState == 4) {
                zaehler=zaehler-1;
                {{formdata.blob}} = {{formdata.request}}.responseText;
                zip.file("{{formdata.Filename}}", {{formdata.blob}});
                //console.log("{{formdata.Filename}}");
                if ( zaehler==0 ) {
                    zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
                    .then(function(content) {
                        // see FileSaver.js
                        saveAs(content, "Anlage.zip");
                    });
                }
            }
        };
    {% endfor %}
};
</script>
```

In the view I just added a context list variable Doku with dict's of individual and uniq variable names to process. This saves from an asynchronous headache.